# Unable to shutdown/restart/hibernate

Tags: 11.04, freeze, shutdown, restart

After I installed ubuntu 11.04, it wont shutdown nor restart, it just freeze, and I have to hold the power button in order to turn off my netbook. (It also happens on livecd)

Can anyone tell me the solution for this?

Comment: Same thing happens to me sometimes but not always, I am then forced to do "sudo shutdown now; exit" from Terminal to ask to shutdown.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug related with wireless driver. This bug has been reported in launchpad.
Asolution is mentioned in Ubuntuforums post [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10796364#post10796364).

Answer (score 2):

What you can do as workaround is to type these commands in a terminal:

To turn the PC off : `sudo shutdown -h now`

To restart the PC : `sudo shutdown -r now`

...anyway this won't solve your problem permanently.

I noticed that when you do some stuff like mounting drives (as root) and you try to turn your PC off from a regular user, you are not allowed. Which is good in terms of security for a Server, but too secure for a Home PC.